# How can I use input data from a userform on word to be later inserted into a excel file that my coding will open

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following coding and I am struggling to Input the data from my userform into an Excel file that my Code will open. I have tried puting in coding which allows the Code to continue once I have clicked submit on my userform, but than it looses the data or just doesn't Input it into the Excel file I selected. This therefore doesn't allow me to copy the necessary data from Excel into my word file.

```
Sub Data()

    UserForm1.Show 'show the userform

    Dim exl As Object 'exl ist der Verweis auf Excel
    Dim oExl As Object

    Dim ImportDatei As Variant


    Set exl = CreateObject("excel.application")
    ImportDatei = exl.Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel-Dateien (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", Title:="Eine Datei auswählen") 'ab exl. wir der Excel Befehl angefügt
    If ImportDatei = False Then Exit Sub


    exl.Workbooks.Open (ImportDatei)
    exl.Visible = True

    'Input data into the excel field
    exl.Range("C1").Select 'Select the cell
    exl.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = TextBox1 'Insert the input Value in the cell
    exl.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$D$65").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" ' Filtern


    ' Product (variante) copy and formating
    exl.Range("A1:A1").Copy
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak 'Insert line space

    ' Copy other relevant info
    exl.Range("A5:A7").Copy
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak

    'Copy table
    exl.Range("A8:D79").Copy
        Selection.Paste
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
End Sub
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as it wasn't working for you, unfortunately I will be busy for the rest of the week so unable to assist further, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the form-code I would say:

You are losing the saved variables from that form because like a sub or function the declarations and assignments made within it are only saved locally.

For example if this code is in your form:

```
Input_Button_Click()

Dim This_String As String
This_string = Textbox1.Value

End Sub
```

And another Sub, even if its within the same module would be:

```
Sub Show_Box_Text ()

MsgBox This_String

End Sub
```

Would show an empty messagebox.

Thats because This_String is only available within the scope of the Userform, Sub or Function in wich it is declared.

**Solution1:**
Call another sub from within the form-code with **arguments from the form** like:

```
Input_Button_Click()

Dim This_String As String
This_string = Textbox1.Value
Call Show_Text_Box(This_String) 'calls another sub or fucntion with argument This_String

End Sub

Sub Show_Box_Text (This_String as String)
'now requires to be called with 1 argument of type String, 
'wich it will, for the duration of this sub refer to as This_String
'name in the calling sub doesnt need to match This_String
MsgBox This_String

End Sub
```

Will show a textbox with right the value or:

**Solution2:**
Make **public** Variables by putting;

```
Public This_String as String 'now publicly available
```

In the "Workbook" or "Document" code

Wich can then be assigned anywhere within the workbook/document by doing:

```
Input_Button_Click()

Thisworkbook.This_String = Textbox1.Value 

End Sub

Sub Show_Box_Text ()

MsgBox Thisworkbook.This_String

End Sub
```

These are IMO the easyest solutions to your problem.

Comment: Hi I tried adding These changes into my Code but it doesnt work. I have uploaded my Code here could you Show me where These changes would go into my Code?

Comment: Private Sub Capturedata_Click()

Thisworkbook.This_String = TextBox1.Value

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

MsgBox Thisworkbook.This_String

End Sub

Comment: I tried that Code but it didnt work for some reason.

Comment: Did you actually put the

Comment: Did you actually put the     Public This_String as String      part in the document/workbook code?